# Title and Meta Description set via Yoast is ignored by Facebook auto-posting plugin(s)

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I have an RTL website (www.aonews.mv) built with WordPress.

- Yoast plugin was installed (primarily to set non-RTL titles and meta descriptions)
- When manually sharing a link on Facebook, the English titles and meta descriptions are recognized flawlessly.
- **However** when a plugin is used to auto-share newest posts on Facebook, no plugin (free or premium) seems to be recognizing English titles set via Yoast. All plugins basically pull the original RTL titles and descriptions from the post. I have tried some of the most top rated plugins that are used auto-post from WP to Social Networks - no success.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wich plugin do you use for share a post ? I think you will have to make a specific function for this...

Comment: Hey Paul, I used a plugin called Social Auto Poster, WP Ultimate Social and  AccessPress Social Auto Post.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all of yours plugins, and use the original Facebook Share Button :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

You can just change the locale in the SDK URL. It is this line of code:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxx&version=v2.0";
```

Just change to "en_US"

Comment: Hey Paul, I do have some share buttons now and they work great. The problem comes up when a post is shared using a plugin that automatically shares newest posts on Facebook. The original post title and body is RTL, but Yoast sections are all in English. If you go to www.aonews.mv, navigate to a single post and try to share it on Facebook, you'll see English title and description pulled. But these plugins pull the original RTL title and first paragraph from the body.

Comment: Hello, so in this case, you have to find the API call who look like this ""//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxx&version=v2.0"" in the source code of your plugin, and apply the famous "en_US" instead of the variable